# How to connect to sqlplus on a remote server using an application (like DataGrip)?

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea, sqlplus, datagrip

I am trying to connect to a remote `sqlplus` (oracle) server using my DataGrip software, but I am not sure how to. I have tried SSH tunnel, through which I am able to successfully connect to the server. But I am not sure what configuration do I need to provide to connect to the actual database. The information I have with me is when on the server, I run the command sqlplus and enter my username and password. I want to be able to connect it to a software for better management of my work.

Comment: SQLPlus is a command line tool. You cannot connect to it. You need to find database connection parameters: port and service name.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what these are through SQLPlus, once I log in?

Comment: Not necessarily; it would depend on the level of access your user has. Even if you see it, you may not necessarily be able to make a direct connection, depending on your network setup. You will need the assistance of your DBA to find out for certain which is the best/acceptable way to make a network connection to the database, and to ensure you have all of the required parameters.

Comment: Have you tried to specify host / port / name / pwd / database name for your instance?

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip works over TCP/IP using JDBC driver. There is no way to connect to `sqlplus`.

For connection via DataGrip one needs to [specify host / port and credentials](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/oracle.html).